# EF 4.0 Entity property setter throws ArgumentOutRangeException

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm working with an [EF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) 4.0 Entity with a property `LanguageCode` of type `String`, which is a two-letter language code such as `DE` or `EN`. There is a referencial constraint and a `Language` navigation property as well, but the `Language` entity set is not included.

I'd like to simply set the language code without loading the `Language` entity. However, the setter throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. More precisely, `ReportPropertyChanges` method in the setter does:

```
OnLanguageCodeChanging(value);
ReportPropertyChanging("LanguageCode");
_LanguageCode = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
ReportPropertyChanged("LanguageCode"); // ArgumentOutOfRangeException
OnLanguageCodeChanged();
```

The `ParamName` is not `value`, but `rowIndex`. That's weird, isn't it?

Google'ing the issue took me to *[Apparent Breaking Change in Framework 4](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqtosql/thread/72dfc0af-3f96-450b-bd80-12f0c29b483b)* (MSDN social). The issue looked similar, but there is no solution. Any faint idea would be very cool... :)

The entity is bound in a Windows Forms application. I tried to reproduce the behaviour in a little demo application, but unfortunately I failed. Maybe the issue is not with the entities themselves?

Edit: Here is the **stack trace** of the exception (including external code):

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, bool cutOverflow) + 0x3f2 bytes
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.GetCellAdjustedDisplayRectangle(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, bool cutOverflow) + 0x3f bytes
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.InvalidateCellPrivate(int columnIndex, int rowIndex) + 0x42 bytes
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellCommonChange(int columnIndex, int rowIndex) + 0x59 bytes
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.ProcessListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0x7dc bytes
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.currencyManager_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e = {System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs}) + 0x43 bytes
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.List_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0x7ec bytes
> DataAccessLayer.dll!DataAccessLayer.Profiles.LanguageCode.set(string value = "DE") Line 13029 + 0x21 bytes    C#
```

Comment: why not just put if (ReportPropertyChanged != null) ReportPropertyChanged("LanguageCode"); I suspect the reason why it throws the error is because there are no event handlers attached to it

Comment: Thanks for your commend Theodore. `EntityObject.ReportPropertyChanged` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject.reportpropertychanged.aspx) isn't an event, but a method. Therefore I'm afraid I can't implement it like this.

Comment: Ok, I see, sorry, then I've got no idea :-(. It seems the only way would be to add the Language entity.

Comment: That exception must have stacktrace so you will see where it was fired.

Comment: Ladislav, thank you very much! Your comment (and maybe some nights of sleep as well), helped me greatly to find the problem. I'd love to mark it as the answer! I used an `List<T>` instead of a `BindingList<T>` as a data source, so no change notifications were provided. Therefore, the new record was not in the grid yet. Now the exception makes perfect send. :)

Comment: @Mudu: That was just a hint. Post your own solution and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List<T>` was bound to a `BindingList`. Both a `DataGrid` and some text boxes for a detail view were bound to it. When I added a new item, the `DataGrid` was not notified (as `List<T>` does not implement `IBindingList`).

The record was not added to the grid yet, so the Windows Forms' binding magic tried to update a cell that was not there.

I solved it like this:

```
myBindingSource.DataSource = new BindingList<T>(myList); // List<T> myList
```

(I found the issue thanks to a hint in the comments.)